# ON DUPLICATE KEY adding rows

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates, unique

OK so I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Tags` (
  `tag_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tag` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tag_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `tag` (`tag`),
  KEY `tag_id` (`tag_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

When I run the following query, it seems to be increasing the primary key even if it finds duplicates (even though it doesn't add the duplicate).

```
INSERT INTO Tags (tag) VALUES ('book'),('cats'),('dogs') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tag = tag
```

You get...

```
tag_id | tag
==============================
1      | book
2      | robots
3      | doodles
5      | cats
6      | dogs
==============================
```

How do I prevent this?

Comment: There's nothing to prevent. The number for `auto_increment` is spent. They are never reused. That's how it works, and if it seems "stupid" - it isn't. If you attempt to "fix" this, you'll actually do harm. Also the query seems out of place, it appears as if you're after `INSERT IGNORE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really prevent this, and you shouldn't worry about it.  Gaps in the auto-incremented id are almost never a problem.

What is happening is that MySQL is attempting to insert the row.  In order to insert the row, it has to construct it -- hence the auto-incremented column is incremented.  When the row is already found, then the insert fails, but the auto-increment is already incremented.

If you want to minimize the problem, you can attempt to find the duplicates *before* attempting the insert:

```
INSERT INTO Tags (tag) 
    SELECT t.tag
    FROM (SELECT 'book' as tag UNION ALL
          SELECT 'cats' as tag UNION ALL
          SELECT 'dogs' as tag
         ) t
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Tags t2 WHERE t2.tag = t.tag)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tag = VALUES(tag);
```

This is not a 100% fix -- the subquery could have duplicates or another process could update the table while this is running.  However, it will generally avoid inserting records when they shouldn't be inserted.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. This makes sense. I'll have to modify my program so it doesn't do these additions unless necessary or i might end up with a very large primary key table. Back to the drawing board :)

Comment: @Hugo - making your pk `bigint` gives you a range of `2^64 - 1`. You should be fine for a few thousand years even if you waste several thousand keys a second :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [innodb_autoinc_lock_mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_autoinc_lock_mode).  What is it currently set to? Setting `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 0` would likely give you what you want, but it defaults to `1`.

Aside, your key `tag_id` (`tag_id`) is redundant since that is already your primary key.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Will modify!